# Cakephp complex hasMany relationship query

Tags: cakephp

I'm very new to CakePHP. I want to do a query in my database like this

```
SELECT m.id, l.*, lp.picture_path 
FROM member m INNER JOIN listing l ON m.member_id = l.member_id
INNER JOIN listingPicture lp ON l.listing_id = lp.listing_id
WHERE lp.picture_default='1'
```

I have 3 models in my cakephp : Member, Listing, and ListingPicture each with the following relationship

- Member hasMany Listing
- Listing hasMany ListingPicture
- Listing belongsTo Member
- ListingPicture belongsTo Listing

From my Member controller how do I execute the query above ?

I've tried

```
$this->Member->Listing->find("all")
```

... which works well but when I added a conditions like this:

```
$this->Member->Listing->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('ListingPicture.picture_default'=>'1')));
```

... I get an error.

Because I'm new to CakePHP, I don't know how to see the error.

Can anyone advise me how I can perform this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set your model as:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then use CakePHP's containable behavior to include only the associated data you want, with specified fields and conditions.

```
$this->Member->Listing->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('*'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Member' => array(
            'fields' => array('id')
        )
        'ListingPicture' => array(
            'conditions' => array('ListingPicture.picture_default' => '1')
            'fields' => array('picture_path')
        )
    )
));
```

To follow with the MVC concept, it's suggested to keep your finds in a Model as opposed to a controller.  It's not required, but - it makes it much easier to know exactly where all finds are, and keeps with the "Fat model / Skinny controler" mantra.  In this case, it'd be something like:

```
//in the Member Controller
$listings = $this->Member->Listing->getListings();

//in the Listing Model
function getListings() {
    $listings = $this->find('all', ...
    return $listings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the condition at the time of binding ListPicture to Listing.

```
$this->Member->Listing->bindModel(array(
  'ListPicture'=>array(
    'condtions'=>array('ListingPicture.picture_default'=>'1')
  ))
);
```